# What is the advantage of the archive button in Thunderbird over a more manual method?

Tags: email, thunderbird

What is the advantage of the archive button in Thunderbird?

Is it just to save me dragging the email into the archive folder? In my case I don't think i'd be bothered with the month and year subfolders so other than that it seems to be effectively the same as if I had created my own archive folder and dragged the mail(s) into it.

Can anyone who uses it explain it's advantage over a more manual method?

Comment: It's just a shortcut.  You can also hit "A" to archive selected messages instead of hitting that button, or use the menu and sleect Messages->Archive.  Basically it's there in case you like to click instead of typing or dragging. ;)   Additional info is in the [release notes for Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.0_-_New_Features_and_Changes#New_.22Archives.22_Folder).  Any 'advantage' would be a personal decision.

Comment: It is just a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional resp. shorter ways to move a mail to the archive:

- "Archive" button that can be added to the toolbar
- Right-click on mail(s) → "Archive" shortcut
- Keyboard shortcut <kbd>a</kbd>

Sub-folder structure that expands automatically by date:

- yearly archived (2011, 2012, …)
- monthly archived (2011-10, 2011-11, …)

Usability:

- not so savvy users might not know they that could create custom folders
- users might not work it out for themselves that moving old mails from the inbox to a different place could be beneficial; thanks to the (prominent) Archive functionality they might try it
- the "Archive" folder gets a special icon

---

If (some of) these features are advantages to you depends on your personal workflow.

Note that you can also mark a custom folder as "Archive" folder for an account: [Configure archive location](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/archived-messages)

Comment: Note that Thunderbird keeps track of messages by conversations (threads) and using the **Archive** button takes advantage of this feature.